# How a big CSS border flows out of the parent element

Tags: html, css, border

[ [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33HbU.png) ]

I have two HTML elements, one of them (the black one) is the parent of the other (the one marked with red line). The size of the child is clearly not bigger than its parent. However, its very big border is making it overflow out of its parent element, the overflow direction is to the right and bottom of the parent. Can I make it overflow to the left and top too? That'll make it appear nicer than it's currently. I've read every single CSS property and didn't find anything to control that behavior.

```
<div style="width: 426px; height: 611px; position: relative; background-color: black;">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 317px; top: 85px; left: 0px; display: block; border: 60px solid red;"></div>
</div>
```

I don't want to make it in the center, because it has a custom position.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ng3Pu/

Comment: Can you post the currently html/css to show us what you're working with.

Comment: Create a fiddle or post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use CSS3

```
Box-sizing: Border-box;
```

but check the compatibility support